# Transfer music files from ubuntu to an mp3 player

Tags: music

Can someone tell me how to transfer music files from ubuntu to an mp3 player?

Comment: To what device would you like to transfer your files?

Comment: a simple sony mp3 player/or an android, not an ipad nor iphone

Comment: Technology has changed over the years.  Have you plugged it in an tried?  Can you be more specific as to what device you're using?

Comment: it shows that is an mp3 file in ubuntu, I drag and drop it in the walkman, and it says that the file is empty. I have this Sony Walkman NWZ-A729 dock

Comment: Have you tried using a media player to transfer the files, such as [`clementine`](https://www.clementine-player.org/)?

Comment: @earthmeLon It works perfectly !! Thank you a lot!!

Comment: Great to hear!  In the future, just try to provide all the details you can at first and we might get it the first time around :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a media player, such as [clementine](https://www.clementine-player.org/).

Many MP3 players will allow you to copy your files directly to the mounted filesystem, but some do not.  It is best to allow your media player to handle these transfers.